# How can I redirect an unauthorized user to a login page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have my own login page. If any user access any page directly (without login), I want to redirect unauthorized user to a login page. How is it possible? Using Generic Handler, is there a chance? Or how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can set this behaviour in the web.config

Example:
(this enables authentication)

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="~/login.aspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

(the specified path is excluded from authentication. meaning you can access the file/directory without authentication. useful for image, scripts, styles directories)

```
<location path="login.aspx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Understand, though, that use must now employ the FormsAuthentication class (as explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx ) Basically the redirect after a successful login must be authorized else it will just keep bouncing your user back to the login aspx.